# Using PIVOT without any aggregate function

Tags: sql-server

I have this table structure that store's employee's attendance daily. I want to get the result so that I could know under the date how many times employee marked attendance if it was checkin it'll give any status let's say IN and if it was checkout it'll say OUT in separate column.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Attendance]    Script Date: 4/24/2019 2:22:47 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attendance](
    [EmpCode] [int] NULL,
    [TimeIn] [datetime] NULL,
    [TimeOut] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employee]    Script Date: 4/24/2019 2:22:47 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Department] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [CenterCode] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Attendance] ([EmpCode], [TimeIn], [TimeOut]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2019-02-01 06:30:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Attendance] ([EmpCode], [TimeIn], [TimeOut]) VALUES (1, NULL, CAST(N'2019-02-01 18:22:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Attendance] ([EmpCode], [TimeIn], [TimeOut]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2019-02-02 07:21:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Attendance] ([EmpCode], [TimeIn], [TimeOut]) VALUES (1, NULL, CAST(N'2019-02-02 19:54:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [EmployeeName], [Department], [CenterCode]) VALUES (1, N'Asim', N'Information Tech', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [EmployeeName], [Department], [CenterCode]) VALUES (2, N'Ali', N'Information Tech', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [EmployeeName], [Department], [CenterCode]) VALUES (3, N'Isaac', N'Information Tech', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [EmployeeName], [Department], [CenterCode]) VALUES (4, N'Swagger', N'Information Tech', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [EmployeeName], [Department], [CenterCode]) VALUES (5, N'Nadine', N'Information Tech', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [EmployeeName], [Department], [CenterCode]) VALUES (6, N'Julie', N'Information Tech', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [EmployeeName], [Department], [CenterCode]) VALUES (7, N'Meachum', N'Information Tech', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [EmployeeName], [Department], [CenterCode]) VALUES (8, N'Bob Lee', N'Information Tech', 4)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attendance]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendance_Employee] FOREIGN KEY([EmpCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attendance] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendance_Employee]
GO
```

Now I have wrote a query but as I'm not sure how to use PIVOT function without aggregate funciton so I'm using MIN() and that's why it's only giving me the first timein/timeout of the day.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT E.ID, E.EmployeeName, T.DateToCheck, COALESCE(A.val, 'Absent') val
    FROM Employee E
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number, '2019-02-01') AS DATE)
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE type = 'P'
        AND DATEADD(DAY, number, '2019-02-01') <= '2019-02-28') T(DateToCheck)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAST(CAST(COALESCE(TimeIn, TimeOut) AS TIME) AS VARCHAR) val, CAST(COALESCE(TimeIn, TimeOut) AS DATE) AttendanceDateTime, EmpCode FROM Attendance) A ON CAST(A.AttendanceDateTime AS DATE) = T.DateToCheck AND A.EmpCode = E.ID
    ) T

PIVOT (MIN(val) FOR DateToCheck IN ([2019-02-01],[2019-02-02],[2019-02-03],[2019-02-04],[2019-02-05],[2019-02-06],[2019-02-07],[2019-02-08],[2019-02-09],[2019-02-10],[2019-02-11],[2019-02-12],[2019-02-13],[2019-02-14],[2019-02-15],[2019-02-16],[2019-02-17],[2019-02-18],[2019-02-19],[2019-02-20],[2019-02-21],[2019-02-22],[2019-02-23],[2019-02-24],[2019-02-25],[2019-02-26],[2019-02-27],[2019-02-28])) P;
```

The expected output result is something like this

```
EmployeeName   Status   2019-02-01   2019-02-02
Asim           IN       06:30        07:21
Asim           OUT      11:39        19:54
Asim           IN       13:06        NULL
Asim           OUT      18:22        NULL
```

Comment: Your actual problem isn't PIVOT but how to count checkings. In any case, you *have* to use an aggregate function. Each row/pivot value combination can have more than one value, which means you need to use an aggregate function to combine them into a single value.

Comment: What you ask is an aggergation anyway - how many times an employee checked in per day, or whether the difference between the checkin/checkout counts is greater or less than 0? How would you write that with a common GROUP BY? PIVOT is essentially a GROUP BY that puts one of the grouping keys in columns. You can start with a GROUP BY that returns the values you want and then add PIVOT to move the date from the GROUP BY clause to the columns